# Linux tattoo: sudo -rm -rf /

Tags: linux

I'm getting a linux tattoo and I though of doing the following:

```
root@127.0.0.1:~#rm -rf /
```

or just:

```
@:~$ sudo -rm -rf /
```

Since it's gonna be on my skin forever, I though of  checking here if there's any typos (specially on the second) or if you guys have any ideas on how to make it cooler. The meaning for me is clearing my mind (I'm probably getting it on the back of the head)

Comment: Regarding the first one: I find it hard to read examples where there's no space between the prompt and the command; put a space between the `#` and the `rm`.  Regarding the second one. there should not be a **`-`** before the `rm`.  And, my personal opinion/preference: long shell prompts may be useful when you're actually working on a terminal, but they're a major distraction when you're presenting or discussing commands.  Just use `# ` or `$ `.

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but you want a Linux tattoo to show your involvement with Linux but don't even know the correct syntax for a simple command?

Comment: For those who may not know - all of these commands are very bad to actually run.

Comment: It may be too late but note that `rm -rf /` will not actually do anything on most systems. It will just return an error. You need `--no-preserve-root`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part up to `#` char (in first case) or `$` (in second) is "prompt", which doesn't do anything important and may look as you like to make it "cooler".

Now, in second case `@:~$ sudo rm -rf /` (without `-` in front of `rm`) would be more correct. You can add `*` at the end if it looks better (`rm -rf /` doesn't always work anyhow) or even remove `/`:

```
@:~$ sudo rm -rf /*              # should work always
@:~$ sudo rm -rf *               # less harmful...
$ rm -rf /*                      # more minimalistic version
```

Other propositions (only commands, take prompt as you like):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda    # probably too long
: >/dev/hda                    # funny erasing
: >/dev/null                   # safe version, harmless
: >/dev/zero                   # similar with zero

: <<\EOF>/dev/null             # |multi-line
EOF                            # |version
```

Comment: Is the @ fine there? Or should always be a username@hostname?

Comment: @raphadko People usually put `user@host` to the prompt to make it more informative, but any characters are fine as it serves purely informative purpose, so `@:~$` is fine as well - it can even happen in reality if for some reason "username" and "hostname" cannot be read, and we are in home `~` directory.

Comment: The `: > ...` commands won't work, because you can't truncate a device, only a file.  A block device's size is fixed (or dependent on loading a tape or CD, but not something you can change with `ftruncate(2)`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, my first advice would be not to get this tattoo, as it won't be as easy to delete as all your files.  But to answer your exact question, I think the command you want is `sudo rm ...` and not `sudo -rm ...`.

#### update

You are getting some bad advice on here, so given the permanence of a tattoo, I highly recommend that you test your actual command in a chroot enviornment (in which you haven't bind-mounted anything important) or in an environment with nothing you care about (like booting from an install USB or Knoppix).

Also, if what you are going for is completely wiping your mind, instead of just deleting all files, then you might want to consider `shred`, which securely deletes a file (`shred /dev/brain`?) or maybe running `trim` after your `rm` command if your brain is an SSD (probably is, right, since one would hope there are no spinning platters up there).  Both of those refinements would seem less iconic and less recognizable to linux aficionados, though, but that's why I kind of think the tattoo is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Hey, don't spoil it. Encourage him to get that tatoo so we can all have a laugh. `sudo -rm rf /` is a great tatoo!

Comment: I bet someone once thought that an MSDOS or OS/2 tattoo would be cool, but technology moves on.